# Coupon Collector's problem, but coupons are distributed by a universal hash function

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins, coupon-collector, hash-function

I am familiar with the Coupon Collector's problem. But what if instead coupons are distributed by a universal hash function? In other (more formal) words, if you hash set $S$ with function $h$ to buckets $B$, how big should $S$ be such that every bucket in $B$ is nonempty? [This paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Book.png) states that hashing $2n^2$ elements to $n$ buckets makes every bucket receive an element with probability $>1/2$. Why is this the case?

The paper is retrieved from https://www.brics.dk/RS/97/16/BRICS-RS-97-16.pdf

Comment: It depends on how random the results of your hash are, which is the point of the paper.  If the hash put balls in buckets uniformly you would only need $O(n \log n)$ balls to cover all the buckets.  $2n^2$ is much worse than this for large $n$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, you are right. However, for a general 2-universal hash function the only information you have is that for any two keys $x,y\in U$, the probability of a collision is $\frac{1}{s}$ where is $s$ is the size of the range. My questions is thus: from this information alone, how can it be derived that hashing $2n^2$ elements to $n$ buckets make every bucket nonempty with probability $>1/2$?